# I'd like to store iTunes music on my new Ubuntu server

Tags: server, music, itunes

I would simply use the server for storage, playing the music through iTunes. Will that work? I have moved iTunes music to other drives in my PC with results that are not so hot - probably from user error, I suppose.
Thanks,
Ken

Comment: What will iTunes be running on?

Comment: iTunes, Windows 10 and iTunes on Mac

Comment: OK, so I can't give details with the Mac platform, but I put our music in a directory and shared the directory w/ Samba, and iTunes running in a Win 10 VM can see it.

Comment: Glad to know. Thanks! I will eventually get this done and try it on the Mac and report back.